# Templated class: unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, class, templates

Using MSVC++ 2010, defining a templated class member outside its declaration block:

```
template <typename T> class cls {
public:
    template <typename T> void bar(T x);
};
template <typename T> void cls<T>::bar(T x) {}
```

yields:

```
unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
1>          definition
1>          'void cls<T>::bar(T)'
1>          existing declarations
1>          'void cls<T>::bar(T)'
```

why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two template declarations because each construct works on a different template argument:

```
template <typename P>
template <typename T>
void cls<P>::bar(T x) {}
```

But it seems to me that `bar` does not need to be templated at all. Use this instead:

```
template <typename T>
class cls
{
    public:
        void bar(T x);
};

template <typename T> void cls<T>::bar(T x) {}
```

Comment: Now I get `llegal use of explicit template arguments`

Comment: In your example you use `template <typename T>` twice. That is what's causing the error. Change the type name to something else.

Comment: You're not supposed to explicitly write template parameter for `bar`, it's being parsed as a partial specialization.

Answer (score 0):

If you're intention is for `bar` to be a member template, then you need this:

```
template <typename T> class cls {
public:
    template <typename U> void bar(U x);
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
void cls<T>::bar(U x) { }
```

Note that, the template parameter of the member must not shadow the class template parameter, hence I changed it to `U`.